# Kohana 2.3.4 : MySQL query to JSON

Tags: mysql, json, kohana, kohana-2

I am managing a project in Kohana 2.3.4 where I need to create an API for my android backend. What I am doing is send a query on my model which returns `$result`.

```
$query = "select product.deal_id,product.deal_key,p..."

$result = $this->db->query($query);
```

**I am not sure if `$result` is an Object or and array** This consists of 4 rows and 8 columns. I need to change $result to json format. I am currently doing this by echoing.

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

This return an empty json `{}`.

I am able to use the same query on my view by iterating through the `$result`

```
foreach ($result as $h){
        echo $h->main_key;
}
```

Am I doing this right or is it that my `$result` on this connection has no rows?

Comment: Maybe the ->query bombed or no rows in resultset. How can we tell

Comment: @AsConfused Hi, I have tested the sql query, as I stated it returns 4 rows and 8 columns on phpmyadmin. Also `$this->db` is my `Database` object.

Comment: But we aren't on phpmyadmin now are we

Comment: @AsConfused yes of course. So what would be the causing the ->query to 'bomb' or not return results if this is the same query I am using on my View?

Comment: Not much code to look at. No error traps to see. Dont even know if u have a connection.

Comment: I quick look reveals that Kohana (v3) is using PDO so after doing a call to PDO::query, you don't get the tuples as array/objects. You get a PDOStatement on which you have to do fetch or fetchAll on. See PDOStatement::fetch for details. `$result = $this->db->query($query)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: @Basti thank you, I figured out my problem using your suggestion. Instead of `fetchAll` all I had to do is call `as_array()`

Answer (score 4):

I figured out I had use Kohana debug to know if my `result` was an object or an array. After calling the following

```
echo Kohana::debug($result);
```

I figured out that it was an object hence the empty result when converted to a json object. I had also tried getting an associative array with `mysql_fetch_assoc` which actually expected a mysql query object. This did
 not work as the object was created by my ORM object. I then solved this by calling

```
$result = $this->db->query($query)->as_array();
```

This returned an array and solved my problem.